# Getting started programming in dynamic languages in Android ((J)Ruby, Clojure...)

Tags: java, android, clojure, jruby, dynamic-languages

I've been looking around, and I can't seem to find any definitive answer or headway that seems "up to date".  I've seen some interesting projects like Mirah (formerly Duby), and am looking into it a bit.  I've seen JRuby unsuccessfully used to compile ruby into .dex.  I've also been looking, independently, into Clojure and have realized that they might all be linked to the same thing.

Does anyone have any tips on how to get started and make headway?  I ask not only what frameworks could help, but more importantly, a philosophy/direction in which to guide my efforts, just to get started.

Comment: I can't parse a question.  "make headway"?  You mean "learn"?

Comment: Learn, as well as getting started with the right tools and development environment.

Comment: If you're just trying to create an Android app quickly (not necessarily in a dynamic language) check out Appcelerator Titanium. You write HTML and JavaScript and it compiles that into native Android code.  To see an example, check out OilReporter in the Android Market, and/or http://oilreporter.org/ to view the source.

Comment: Add the moment you are not really able to write apps for android in anything other then Java or C++, or JavaScript if your whole app runs in a WebView. 

Titanium might be a good way, all the other languages may have to wait a little bit until they are properly ported etc.

Comment: @Janusz What sort of technologies would I be waiting for to come about, to signal the day that I should start developing?

Comment: There is a project running trying to get mono on android. This would allow you to use ironruby and ironpython on android and also reuse parts of your code between iphone and android because mono for iphone is already working. Search for MonoDroid for more information I couldn't find the official project page at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002566/can-i-program-for-android-using-any-jvm-language/3002655#3002655).  Have you considered Scala?  I know its not a dynamic language, but it seems to be the best alternative to Java right now.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question =)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Dynamic JVM languages like JRuby, Clojure, or Jython have severe performance problems on the Android Dalvik JVM. Until Dalvik gets friendlier to dynamic languages you are pretty much out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

JRuby (its Android distribution is called [Ruboto](http://ruboto.org/), you can try out [Ruboto IRB](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.org-ruboto-irb-jqmwq.aspx) now) works in interpreted mode on Android, and though [dx has some problems in compiling all of the JRuby standard library](http://blog.headius.com/2010/04/building-ruboto-precompiling-ruby-for.html), the JRuby devs seem to want to solve that problem on their end, so I'd keep an eye on JRuby, becasue the issues are likely to be solved soonish.

It also looks like it's possible for dx to compile just the portion of the standard library that you're interested in using for a given app.