# What languages are mature to develop native apps in Android [except Java]

Tags: android, scala, clojure, jruby

Is there a languages other then Java to develop native apps in android without script layer/AIR and others 3rd party abstractions.

Mostly im interested in Clojure,JRuby, Scala

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002566/can-i-program-for-android-using-any-jvm-language

Comment: seems year ago all was about hacks and proofs of concept.. is it same now?

Comment: Humm, I would not expect "official" built in support for functional programming in Android ever. They have more immediate problems to solve by now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Scala is compiled to native JVM bytecode, it could be use to develop native Android apps.

The biggest problem is that using 3rd party library is not that easy in Android development, and you need use proguard to reduce the size of your program, sometimes this will cause problem.

But it is still feasible to develop an Android app using Scala, for example, I've wrote [an little android app](http://bone.twbbs.org.tw/maidroid/node/5) (page in Chinese, but there is screenshots) using Scala. It's not a complex app, but should demonstrate what Scala could do in Android app development.

Here is also an [SBT plugins](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin) that help you build your Scala/Android program.

Finally, if you want develop Android using Scala, I will suggest using Scala 2.8.x. I found my program crashes during adb install when I extends a collection class using Scala 2.9.

Comment: u wrote this program long ago, have u going futher with Scala on Android field?

Comment: @Umern: I still write my own Android program now and didn't encounter much problem (except some 3rd party library, which is also a pain even you use Java), just not releases in public. And I think current state is already sufficient for me. SBT works great for me (I like VIM/SBT over IDEs), and I could use stable version of Scala 2.8. I have no idea what "further" I need to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mirah, you can get code that is exactly as fast and small as writing Java, but you get niceties like type inference, closures, and macros. The tooling is still pretty immature compared to Scala, but if you want to minimize overhead above all else you should give it a look: http://mirah.org and https://github.com/mirah/pindah